# Spark Timestamp issue, same timestamp but mismatching

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp

I am moving data from source into my bucket and need to write a script for data validation. But for Timestamp data type, I face some weird issue: I have two rows containing two same timestamp [2017-06-08 17:50:02.422437], [2017-06-08 17:50:02.422], because the second one is having a different format due to different file system configuration Spark considers them different. Is there anyway to resolve this problem? The ideal way is to ignore this column when doing data frame comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unix_timestamp and use that number for comparison. For actual date requirements you can use from_unixtime to convert to your required format. Not sure it is efficient method on large volume of data...

```
 sqlContext.sql("Select unix_timestamp('2017-06-08 17:50:02.422'), unix_timestamp('2017-06-08 17:50:02.422437') ").show
```

```
+----------+----------+
|       _c0|       _c1|
+----------+----------+
|1496958602|1496958602|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: This makes sense, let me have a try and see how it works.